# The number of featured questions on questions and main page don't match

Tags: bug, frontpage

The number of featured questions on the questions and the main page don't match: 63 vs. 64

questions:
[image]
main
[image]

Why was that?

I don't think that my [standing bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519455/19341) is counted as well...

Comment: @ArthurFischer yes, I edited. As for my "standing bounty", the [revisions](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/519455/revisions) show that I actually added a bounty. In the optional text I promised another +100 and after the bounty period I added a note to the body, where I promised +150. This I raised to +200. Thanks for the hint how to start a bounty but I already spent [1750 of reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/19341/draks?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on this feature...

Comment: @ArthurFischer any idea why they didn't match?

Comment: Sorry, I apologise. (One time where the revision list would have been much more clear than the timeline, dammit.) At any rate, I have no idea why there was a mismatch at the time.  I would expect (hope) that the information is all pulled from the same place and in the same way from the database.  Is it at all possible that a new bounty was added in the interval between the the loading of the pages in question? With only the screenshots at hand I cannot even guess at a different cause.

Comment: @ArthurFischer it is happening again right now: 58 vs 59...

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to catch it myself.  Actually, I caught a 60 v. 58 discrepancy. I officially have no clue whatsoever what is causing this.

Comment: What's more odd is that I found **three** questions from `Main > featured` (claiming 60 questions) that weren't in the list from `Questions > featured` (claiming 58 questions): [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/590716/8348), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/575894/8348), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183199/8348).

Comment: @ArthurFischer for test reasons a started a [bounty](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/477699/19341), which immediatley popped up on main [(screenshot, just note the counters, displayed one is not mine)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i7VUQ.png)...